# Assign a value if two elements in different dataset are equal

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have two datasets with different dimensions and I would like to attach a value in a new variable for the rows that are equal.

```
> data
  a     b
1 TR123 P823   
2 TR123 P842   
3 TR456 P846   
4 TR456 P904 

> data2
  d     f     c
1 TR456 P846  UN
2 P904  TR456 REL
3 P904  TR453 REL
```

And I would like to have this kind of data:

```
> data
  a     b    c
1 TR123 P823 NA    
2 TR123 P842 NA  
3 TR456 P846 UN  
4 TR456 P904 REL
```

I tried to solve my problem with ifelse, apply or a for loop but it does not work. 
for example:

```
data$c<-ifelse(data$a==data2$d&data$b==data2$f, data2$c,
     ifelse(data$a==data2$f&data$b==data2$d,data2$c, NA))
```

I am looking forward for your suggestions!

Comment: try `merge.data.frame` or `left_join` from `dplyr`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
data=tibble(a=c("TR123","TR123","TR456","TR456"),b=c("P823 ","P842","P846","P904"))
data2=tibble(a=c("TR456","P904","P904"),b=c("P846","TR456","TR453"),c=c("UN","REL","REL"))
dataRows=((data$a %in% data2$a | data$a %in% data2$b)&(data$b %in% data2$a| data$b %in% data2$b))%>%which() 
data2Rows=((data2$a %in% data$a | data2$a %in% data$b)&(data2$b %in% data$a| data2$b %in% data$b))%>%which() 
data$c<-NA
data$c[dataRows]<-data2$c[data2Rows]

> data
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  a     b       c    
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1 TR123 "P823 " NA   
2 TR123 P842    NA   
3 TR456 P846    UN   
4 TR456 P904    REL
```

Comment: Hi @Antonis ! thanks a lot for your suggestions! But it does not work. The values in the two columns that I need to compare are exchangeable, they are indeed mixed. That is why I had two ifelse. In the second dataset I also have much more rows with information that I do not need, in fact R tells me that the two columns: joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector. I also tried with     merge  (@missuse) but it merged the information only for a part of the common couples.